# binary file read/write error containing char* pointer within struct

Tags: c, binaryfiles, fwrite

I have a strange problem. I can not guess why it is happening. I tried in various ways. May be it is because still I am newbie for c language.

Please look at the below code.

It comes with 2 arguments. `--write` and `--read`.

- In my `write()` function I write to the file and then I call the `read()` function. This write the data to file and print 3 lines of values correctly as expected.
- In my `read()` function I read the file. When I pass the `--read` argument alone , the program gives `segmentation fault` error message. Although in below code if I assign the static string value to `char *name` this read function works as expected.

Below is my full code that I created to simulate my issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _student {
    int id;
    char *name;
} Student;

void write();
void read();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (strcmp(argv[1], "--write") == 0) {
            write();
            read();
        }
        else if (strcmp(argv[1], "--read") == 0) {
            read();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void write()
{
    printf("Write\n");
    FILE *fp;

    // write student
    Student *std_writer = (Student *) malloc(sizeof(Student));
    std_writer->id = 10;
    //std_writer->name = "Alice"; // But if i remove the below 4 lines and uncommented this line, everything works as expected.
    char *a = "Alice";
    std_writer->name = malloc(20);
    memset(std_writer->name, '\0', 20);
    strncpy(std_writer->name, a, 5);

    fp = fopen("Student.file", "wb");
    fwrite(std_writer, sizeof(Student), 1, fp);
    fwrite(std_writer, sizeof(Student), 1, fp);
    fwrite(std_writer, sizeof(Student), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    free(std_writer);
}

void read()
{
    printf("Read\n");
    FILE *fp;

    // read student
    Student *std_reader = (Student *) malloc(sizeof(Student));
    fp = fopen("Student.file", "rb");
    while(fread(std_reader, sizeof(Student), 1, fp) == 1) {
        printf("ID %i  \tName : %s\n", std_reader->id, std_reader->name);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    free(std_reader);
}
```

please help me understand and solve this issue.

**EDIT**

Ok According to the below answers as I understood, I udpated my struct Student as follows.

```
typedef struct _student {
    int id;
    char name[20];
} Student;
```

This works.

Any comments ?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: The really short answer: You're saving the pointer, but not the stuff it points to.

Comment: "*Any comments ?*" what if the name to store is longer than 19 characters?

Comment: You should not have updated your struct. `name` should stay a pointer or be a flexible array member.

Comment: If you really want the `name` to have a fixed size, at least make it much longer (64 bytes, not 20). But you should not make it of fixed size!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it depends on the program. For learning purposes, this is fine as long as there are no names longer than 19 characters. For real world use, either do what you said, or increase it to something like 1024 characters and make sure to reject names longer than 1023. Preferably the former so you can deal with any length names.

Comment: No in my real application I store mac address.

Comment: @BlueBird: make your real application free software on e.g. http://github.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call your functions `read` and `write` (these names are for Posix functions). And don't expect to be able to read again a pointer written by a different [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

So in your `write` you are (assuming a 64 bits x86 system, e.g. a Linux one) writing 12 bytes (4 i.e. `sizeof(int)` + 8 i.e. `sizeof(char*)`); the last 8 bytes are the numerical value of some `malloc`-ed pointer.

In your `read` your are reading these 12 bytes. So you are setting the `name` field to the numerical pointer which happened to be valid in the process which has done the `write`. This won't work in general (e.g. because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)).

In general, doing I/O on pointers is very bad. It has only sense for the same process.

What you want to do is called [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). For [software engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_engineering) reasons I recommend using textual format for serialization (e.g. [JSON](http://json.org/), perhaps using the [Jansson](http://www.digip.org/jansson/) library). Textual formats are less brittle, and easier to debug.

---

Assuming you would encode a student in JSON format like

```
{ "id":123, "name":"John Doe" }
```

here is a possible JSON encoding routine using Jansson:

```
int encode_student (FILE*fil, const Student*stu) {
   json_t* js = json_pack ("{siss}", 
                           "id", stu->id, 
                           "name", stu->name);
   int fail = json_dumpf (js, fil, JSON_INDENT(1));
   if (!fail) putc('\n', fil);
   json_decref (js); // will free the JSON
   return fail;  
}
```

Notice that you need a function to free a `malloc`-ed `Student` zone, here it is:

```
void destroy_student(Student*st) {
   if (!st) return;
   free (st->name);
   free (st);
}
```

and you might want also the macro

```
#define DESTROY_CLEAR_STUDENT(st) do \
  { destroy_student(st); st = NULL; } while(0)
```

Now, here is the JSON decoding routine using Jansson; it gives a `Student` pointer in heap (to be later destroyed by the caller with `DESTROY_CLEAR_STUDENT`).

```
Student* decode_student(FILE* fil) { 
   json_error_t jerr;
   memset (&jerr, 0, sizeof(jerr));
   json_t *js = json_loadf(fil, JSON_DISABLE_EOF_CHECK, &err);
   if (!js) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to decode student: %s\n", err.text);
      return NULL;
   }
   char* namestr=NULL;
   int idnum=0;
   if (json_unpack(js, "{siss}",  
                       "id", &idnum,
                       "name", &namestr)) {
       fprintf(stderr, "failed to unpack student\n");
       return NULL;
   };
   Student* res = malloc (sizeof(Student));
   if (!res) { perror("malloc student"); return NULL; };
   char *name = strdup(namestr);
   if (!name) { perror("strdup name"); free (res); return NULL; };
   memset(res, 9, sizeof(Student));
   res->id = id;
   res->name = name;
   json_decref(js);
   return res;
}
```

---

You could also decide that you serialize in some binary format (I don't recommend doing that). Then you should define your serialization format and stick to it. Very probably you'll have to encode the student id, the length of the its name, its name....

You could also (in C99) decide that the student's `name` is a [flexible array member](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzarg/flexible.htm), that is declare

```
typedef struct _student {
   int id;
   char name[]; // flexible member array, conventionally \0 terminated
} Student;
```

---

You really want the student names to be of varying length. You then cannot simply put varying length records in a simple `FILE`. You could use some indexed file library like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org/s/gdbm/%E2%80%8E) (each record could be in JSON). And you probably want to use [Sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) or a real database like [MariaDb](https://mariadb.org/) or [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

Comment: your reply makes me sense. How should I change my program to write the value correctly. Do i need to change my struct?

Comment: I change the char pointer in struct to char array. now it works fine. Do you think is this right solution?

Comment: No, you don't need to change that (but you could). If it is an array, make it a flexible array member. But you always should serialize properly.

Comment: @BlueBird there is no single right answer, like with most questions like "how do I do something?". Emanuele Paolini's answer states two possibilities.

Comment: in my case I can not serialize, Becuase I need to execute search on this file. The above code is not my real code. I created the above to simulate my issee in simple number of lines. for the application I am creating,, searching is mandatory.

Comment: You need a student name of variable length. So each record has to be of variable length; so you cannot search in the file that easily.

Comment: What if I want to use variable length without json?

Comment: You have to deal with that manually, byte by byte, computing various offsets etc.

Comment: if you seee in my code, I am using `malloc` to allocate memory and `memset` to set termination character then I copy the value to char pointer `name`. Now I found it is wrong somewhere. right? If this way is wrong, can you give me an example for that. coz, in my real application I write the data which is taken from mysql database.

Comment: @BlueBird: Show your real code (perhaps by publishing it on http://github.com/ as free software). Then ask another question. What you are saying in recent comments (mysql, MAC addresses) is really very far from your original question.

Comment: yes ofcourse, real code is combination of several file which create file and wich call file.. which search in file... To make the scenario simple I simulated with a student DB that has my real issue.

Comment: hope mysqlite would help me. I will check that also.

Answer (score 4):

Notice that you are not writing the name of the student to file. Your are only writing the pointer to that string. This, for sure, is not what you want. When you read the file you are reading the pointer which is no longer valid.

Either put the entire string in your struct (not a char pointer but a char array) or else you should separately write the strings to file.

Answer (score 1):

In `read()`, you don't ever allocate memory for `name` in your `Student` structure. (Your `write()` function is much better behaved in that respect.)

When you refer to it in you `printf` statement, you invoke *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: if you notice, when I pass the argument `--write` .. after writing,, i call the same `read()` function. that time it works. the variables inside `read()` functions are completely independent. ..

Comment: ok.. should I put a malloc like `std_reader->name = (char *) malloc(20);` this in read function above the `while` ?

Comment: I don't understand your first comment: If you allocate a new `Student` then you'll need to allocate memory for `name` too. As for your second comment: yes, allocate as much memory as you do when you write. And don't forget the null terminator.